# How can I enable the "GROUP BY" aggregation dimension as the input for a function created in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregation, table-functions

I need to create a table with the same aggregations at multiple different levels in BigQuery, for example:

```
SELECT 
dimension_a, 
dimension_b, 
SUM(value) AS value 
FROM mydataset.table 
GROUP BY dimension_a, dimension_b

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
dimension_a, 
NULL AS dimension_b, 
SUM(value) AS value 
FROM mydataset.table 
GROUP BY dimension_a

UNION ALL

SELECT 
NULL AS dimension_a, 
dimension_b, 
SUM(value) AS value 
FROM mydataset.table 
GROUP BY dimension_b
```

I guess it is not the most elegant codes... for example, I have 18 different aggregation dimensions, that means I need to stack those similar code blocks 18 times with `UNION ALL`, I am wondering if there could be a function that allows me to have the aggregation dimension as the input?

For example, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION mydataset.aggregation_dimension(X type, Y type)
AS
  SELECT
  X as dimension_a, Y as dimension_b,
  SUM(value) AS value
  FROM mydataset.table 
  GROUP BY X, Y;

SELECT * FROM mydataset.aggregation_dimension(dimension_a, dimension_b)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mydataset.aggregation_dimension(dimension_a, NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mydataset.aggregation_dimension(NULL, dimension_b)
```

Where X, Y should be a column in the table `mydataset.table` ... However, I have no idea how to define the type of this kind of inputs. I also don't know if it is possible to have such a setting...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you considered `GROUP BY ROLLUP` ?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause

Comment: Thanks! at least this make my query simplier！